# How to add type hint for all protocol buffer objects in python functions?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, type-hinting

I want to add type hints for arguments in functions that accept *any* [google protocol](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) buffer object.

```py
def do_something(protobuf_obj: WHAT_IS_HERE):
    # protobuf_obj can be any protocol buffer instance
    pass
```

What class should I put there from the `google.protobuf` library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using the [`Message`](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/message.html#google.protobuf.message.Message) abstract base class. From the docs:

> `class google.protobuf.message.Message`
>
> Abstract base class for protocol messages.
>
> Protocol message classes are almost always generated by the protocol compiler. These generated types subclass Message and implement the methods shown below.

So, now it looks like:

```py
from google.protobuf.message import Message

def do_something(protobuf_obj: Message):
    # protobuf_obj can be any protocol buffer instance
    pass
```

Answer (score -2):

[PEP 688](https://peps.python.org/pep-0688/)

Looks like this functionality will be implemented in Python 3.12.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32017335)

Comment: The question is asking about google's protocol buffer, but the link referenced is for python built-in types.

Comment: This is irrelevant for the same reason @kenny mentioned. OP is asking about Google's Protocol Buffers in regards to python, while the link you provided is in reference to python's "buffer protocol" which is how Python wraps access to underlying buffers for built-in types.